# How to handle non-ascii characters in HTTP request header?

Tags: http, .net-core

In our application, we are sending passwords as part of the header for authentication to our auth service. However, we're running into a situation where users are using non-ascii characters as part of their password, and I found out that non-ascii characters are not supported in HTTP.

What are some approaches to handling this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode it in an ASCII compatible format.

[Base 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is such an encoding.

Here is an exemple of how they did it for the [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) using Base 64 encoding.

> The Authorization field is constructed as follows:
>
> - The username and password are combined with a single colon (:). This means that the username itself cannot contain a colon.
> - The resulting string is encoded into an octet sequence. The character set to use for this encoding is by default unspecified, as long as it is compatible with US-ASCII, but the server may suggest use of UTF-8 by sending the charset parameter.
> - The resulting string is encoded using a variant of Base64.
> - The authorization method and a space (e.g. "Basic ") is then prepended to the encoded string.
>
> For example, if the browser uses `Aladdin` as the username and `OpenSesame` as the password, then the field's value is the base64-encoding of `Aladdin:OpenSesame`, or `QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l`. Then the Authorization header will appear as:
>
> ```
> Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l
> ```

So let's say your password is `ǁǂǃǄǅǆǇǈǉǊǋǌǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔǕǖǗǘǙǚǛǜǝǞǟ`, which cannot be represented using the ASCII charset.

Here is some pseudo code showing you how to do it

```
var password = 'ǁǂǃǄǅǆǇǈǉǊǋǌǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔǕǖǗǘǙǚǛǜǝǞǟ'
var base64EncodedPassword = base64Encode(password)

var httpHeader = new HttpHeader('Password', base64EncodedPassword)
```

And it would results in the following header. Represented using only ASCII char

```
Password: x4HHgseDx4THhceGx4fHiMeJx4rHi8eMx43HjsePx5DHkceSx5PHlMeVx5bHl8eYx5nHmsebx5zHnceex58=
```